# Rails 6 + Webpack, Datatables, jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, datatables, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a "Select All" button that uses this code:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#check_all').on("click", function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click();
  });
</script>
```

Since I upgraded to Rails 6 + Webpacker, it stopped working.
The console shows this error:

```ruby
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I managed to fix it by altering `environment.js` from:

```ruby
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
```

To:

```ruby
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
```

But once that's fixed, datatables breaks.

Any ideas how to have them both working together?
Thanks!

Comment: Your `environment.js` was correct. Which source line caused `ReferenceError`? Where is the code for "Select All" button and how it sourced into `application.js` pack?

Comment: More info on this datatables error ?

Comment: @LyzardKyng this line: `$('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });` The code sits in the related view. When I try to move it into application.js it doesn't give an error anymore but the button also doesn't do anything. Any ideas? Here's what it looks like in application.js: `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
})` -- I'm super new to all this so I'm probably making a mistake

Comment: @overlox here's the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined` and here's the offending line: `    this.$ = function (sSelector, oOpts) {` the actual problem is that dt doesn't load at all. No search, no pagination, etc.

Comment: @MaayanNaveh did you change `javascript_include_tag` to `javascript_pack_tag` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`? I repeat your code and I don't see any errors and checkbox is ticked as expected.

Comment: @LyzardKyng yup, just double checked and it's `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: https://inopinatus.org/2019/09/14/webpacker-jquery-and-jquery-plugins/

Comment: @inopinatus Excellent systematized reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moving your own Javascript into the pack file was a good choice for maintainability.  However, I'm guessing those are dynamically generated checkboxes.  They may not exist when the bind runs.  You can rise above the problem by binding to a parent element and using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). `document.body` is a common binding choice for delegated events with Turbolinks.

I'm not a fan of calling click() on a checkbox.  The result isn't always consistent for users, and it fires off a bunch of unnecessary events in the browser.  Inverting the `checked` prop is cleaner and more consistent.

Getting DataTables to load as a module requires an import shim.  It's an older package that prefers AMD over CommonJS and trips over itself in the Webpack environment.   Fortunately, there's a standard fix for older code, using the [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/).  Unfortunately, even then it's got a slightly strange factory export, into which you're expected to inject the `window` and `jQuery` variables.  Fortunately it's also [documented here](https://datatables.net/download/npm).

Putting that all together, here's a suggested `application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import $ from 'jquery'

// Add DataTables jQuery plugin
require('imports-loader?define=>false!datatables.net')(window, $)
require('imports-loader?define=>false!datatables.net-select')(window, $)

// Load datatables styles
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css'
import 'datatables.net-select-dt/css/select.dataTables.css'

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
  $(document.body).on('click', '#check_all', () => {
    var checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
    checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"))
  })

  // placeholder example for datatable with checkboxes
  $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      render: (data,type,row) => `<input type="checkbox" value="${row[0]}">`,
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0
    }],
    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
  })
})
```

You'll need to `yarn add imports-loader`, since it's a Webpack option.

The ProvidePlugin is not required for any of this.  Unless you're depending on it for injection of imports to third-party code, it can be safely removed.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the well written reply! I really appreciate you putting the time :) I gave it a try and didn't manage to get it to work. I have resolved all the issues and it seems to compile okay, but there is no pagination/search (meaning, dt won't load). The console shows 1 error but with no indication as to which code line is the offender. The error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` . Here is my `application,js`: https://gist.github.com/maayannaveh/51de9d29d89181b104ae2076d17a08e1 (I have commented out the styles because I'm not sure how to make it work just yet)

Comment: Okay, managed to get styles to work. Same thing. One error, no offending line, dt doesn't load :(

Comment: You have undisclosed script elements or event attributes that are trying to use the `$` global and failing because there isn't one. Move all such code into packs. I can't see that you've added any code to actually invoke DataTables - that "placeholder example" section is just that, adapt it for your own application.

Comment: You also have a duplicate import of jquery. Delete the `require('jquery')`. Probably not harmful, but certainly redundant and confusing.

Comment: After 3 days of googling this answer finally got my custom jquery code working in Rails 6. Bless you.

Comment: @inopinatus I am facing the same error but your solution does not work in my case

Answer (score 2):

run `yarn add imports-loader`

I use bootstrap4 datatable if you use bootstrap3 or other CSS frameworks, please  follow the installation from this link:
https://datatables.net/download/

in my `config/webpack/loaders/datatable.js`

```
module.exports = {
  test: /datatables\.net.*/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false'
  }]
}
```

in my `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')
const datatable =  require('./loaders/datatable')

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

/**
 * To use jQuery in views
 */
environment.loaders.append('expose', {
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [{
    loader: 'expose-loader',
    options: '$'
  }]
})

environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', datatable)

module.exports = environment
```

in my `app/javascript/packs/dashboard.js`

```
require( 'jszip' );

require("datatables.net-bs4")(window, $);
require("datatables.net-responsive-bs4")(window, $);
require("datatables.net-buttons-bs4")(window, $);
require("datatables.net-select-bs4")(window, $);

require("datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css");
require("datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.css");
require("datatables.net-buttons-bs4/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css");
require("datatables.net-select-bs4/css/select.bootstrap4.css");
```

Feel free to user
`import './datatable'` at any `.js` file in `app/javascript/packs` you like

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. Finally got it to work by following this guide: https://inopinatus.org/2019/09/14/webpacker-jquery-and-jquery-plugins/.

`yarn add datatables.net-bs4 imports-loader`

application.js

```
require('@rails/ujs').start()
require('@rails/activestorage').start()
require('channels')
require('jquery')
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap')
window.$ = $

require('imports-loader?define=>false!datatables.net')(window, $)
require('imports-loader?define=>false!datatables.net-bs4')(window, $)
```

Comment: This solved my problem (which didn't even exist when I was on jQuery version 3.4.1, but only appeared when I upgraded jQuery to v3.5.0). And this is by far the simplest and cleanest of the provided answers.

Comment: Since I authored that guide, _and_ the top-rated answer above, I'll add my thoughts:)

You've applied the same principle and correctly so, but for a different version and/or set of imports. I suspect what's happened is that some of the external pieces changed their behaviour or packaging.

Comment: window.$ = $ sorted it for me